# How not to set data alphabetically sorted in Firebase in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set an object in my Firebase data. While adding in database its added alphabetically sorted.
Doing something like,

```
const dbCon = props.db.database().ref('/pages/page');
dbCon.set({dataForFirebase});
```

It's setting data in the database sorted already in https://console.firebase.google.com/project/someProject/data.
How do I prevent this? Or how do get the data as the object has the order?

To fetch the data I am doing:

```
static async getIndividualCompoenetDetails () {
   const app = await firebase.database().ref('pages/page');
   const snapshot = await app.once('value');
   const { dataForFirebase } = snapshot.val();
   return dataForFirebase;
}
```

Comment: I wrote some basic definitions of how Firebase works below. It's hard to provide feedback on your code though, since `firebase.database().ref('pages/page').once('value'` already retrieves a single JSON node, so I'm not sure what order you're referring to there.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over how the database stores the data. The fact that you add the data in a certain order has no influence on how it's stored. If the order is important, store it under a key or with a property that records this order, e.g. by calling `ref.push()` to add new child nodes.

The Firebase console displays the data lexicographically ordered by key. This is not configurable, but sounds like a useful feature. I'd recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for it, although I'll admit that I haven't heard the request frequently enough that I think it's going to be implemented.

Whenever you call `snapshot.val()` the data from the snapshot is converted to a JSON object, which is by definition not ordered.